# jquery .wrap() only uwrapped elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Need help with such a problem. I've got infinite scrolling in my WP site, and on every ajax page load this code is executing:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
   $('iframe[src*="youtube.com"]').unwrap('<div class="youtubeWrapper" />').wrap('<div class="youtubeWrapper" />');
   $('iframe[src*="vimeo.com"]').unwrap('<div class="vimeoWrapper" />').wrap('<div class="vimeoWrapper" />');
   $('iframe[src*="coub.com"]').unwrap('<div class="coubWrapper" />').wrap('<div class="coubWrapper" />');});
```

It wraps iframes with div. The only problem is that wrapping reloads iframe. So is there any way not to touch already wrapped elements?

Comment: Add a specific class to already wrapped element to exclude them from matched set using relevant selector. I mean, you could use: `$('iframe[src*="youtube.com"]:not(.wrapped)').wrap('<div class="youtubeWrapper" />').addClass('wrapped');`. Or without any extra class: `$('iframe[src*="youtube.com"]:not(.youtubeWrapper > iframe)').wrap('<div class="youtubeWrapper" />');`

Comment: dropping it here https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13574

Comment: Super! $('iframe[src*="youtube.com"]:not(.wrapped)').wrap('<div class="youtubeWrapper" />').addClass('wrapped'); is working great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can check for it's parent first before wrapping, like

```
var youtubeIframe= $('iframe[src*="youtube.com"]');
youtubeIframe.parent().is(".youtubeWrapper") && youtubeIframe.wrap('<div class="youtubeWrapper" />');
```